# NumberFormatException: trouble to set rating to ratingbar in listview

Tags: android, set, rating, ratingbar

I am trying to set rating to Ratingbar which is located in Listview but not able to set it.I am stuck on this part but till i didn't got answer.  My rating bar is not clickable.
Here is my xml file code

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1" />
```

Here is my code to set rating to rating bar. Actually i am fetching value from json file and then i cast it in float. Look at this.

```
static final String TAG_DISHRATING = "dishrating";
.... 
float dishRating = Float.valueOf(dishResult.getString(TAG_DISHRATING));//parse from json file  
.....
//then i add it i hashmap  
map.put(TAG_DISHRATING, String.valueOf(dishRating));
// Then i am getting it form map   
 for(HashMap hm:songsList) 
  if(hm.get(TAG_lOCATIONNAME).equals(name)) 
  {                     
    dishid = Integer.parseInt(hm.get(TAG_DISHiD).toString());
    float dishrating = Float.parseFloat(hm.get(TAG_DISHRATING).toString());                     
  }
```

And finally i am setting rating to rating bar

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);// rating bar

    ratingBar.setClickable(false);
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(HotelList.TAG_lOCATIONNAME));
    artist.setText(song.get(HotelList.TAG_DISHTOTALVOTES));
    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING)); //here i am getting exception
```

Logcat Exception:

```
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "dishrating"
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:310)
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
01-07 13:10:24.250: E/AndroidRuntime(25565):    at com..LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:57)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING));
```

should be

```
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(song.get(HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING)));
```

because current you are trying to parse string to Float. pass right value to `Float.parseFloat`

Comment: my tag_dishrating is string. i use your code but it showing The method setRating(float) in the type RatingBar is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil : use ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(song.get(HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING))); line see my answer

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil : pass value of `dishrating` string instead of "dishrating"

Comment: ..Thanks's a lot.. you solve my problem . but can you tell what exactly i did wrong...

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil : song is map and you are passing `HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING` to `Float.parseFloat` so you will need to first pick value from song using `HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING` key and then pass value instead of key to `Float.parseFloat`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(song.get(HotelList.TAG_DISHRATING)));
```